# How do I access a custom tag in a company's 10q filing?

Tags: python, edgar, sec

My issue concerns how to access non us-gapp tagged company data in, for example, a 10-q for the ticker MSFT. See this 10q filing: https://www.sec.gov/ix?doc=/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000095017023054855/msft-20230930.htm

Normally, I can just use the following code based on the us-gaap key to get the value:

```
dep_amort_data = companyFacts.json()['facts']['us-gaap'].get('DepreciationDepletionAndAmortization', {})
```

[image: Corresponding attributes panel]

However, some stocks, like MSFT, use custom tags for certain values:

[image: MSFT custom tag example]

When substituting in 'msft' for 'us-gaap'(and the other language) in the previously stated code, no value is found, so a simple key change doesn't work apparently.

```
dep_amort_data = companyFacts.json()['facts']['msft'].get('DepreciationAmortizationAndOther', {})
```

I am wondering if anyone knows how to resolve this, because there is clearly a value available per the second image. Perhaps the value is not stored in 'facts'?

Thank you.

Added full method (removed email):

```
def fetch_data_from_sec_edgar(cik, ticker):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'EMAIL',
    }

    # Get company facts data
    companyFacts = requests.get(
        f'https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyfacts/CIK{cik}.json',
        headers=headers
    )

    # Check for successful response
    if companyFacts.status_code != 200:
        print("Failed to fetch company facts")
        return 0

    # Try to fetch the depreciation and amortization data from the latest 10-Q
    try:
        
        if dep_amort_data:
            # Filter for 10-Q filings
            dep_amort_10q_data = [item for item in dep_amort_data.get('units', {}).get('USD', []) if item['form'] == '10-Q']
            if dep_amort_10q_data:
                # Find the most recent entry
                most_recent_dep_amort = max(dep_amort_10q_data, key=lambda x: x['end'], default={})
                return most_recent_dep_amort.get('val', 0)
            else:
                print("No 10-Q Depreciation and Amortization Data Found")
                return 0
        else:
            tag_ticker = ticker.lower()
            dep_amort_data = companyFacts.json()['facts'][tag_ticker].get('DepreciationAmortizationAndOther', {})
            if dep_amort_data:
                dep_amort_10q_data = [item for item in dep_amort_data.get('units', {}).get('USD', []) if item['form'] == '10-Q']
                print(dep_amort_10q_data)
                if dep_amort_10q_data:
                    # Find the most recent entry
                    most_recent_dep_amort = max(dep_amort_10q_data, key=lambda x: x['end'], default={})
                    return most_recent_dep_amort.get('val', 0)
                else:
                    print("No 10-Q Depreciation and Amortization Data Found")
                    return 0 
            else:
                print("No Depreciation and Amortization Data Found")
                return 0
        
    except KeyError as e:
        print(f"Error fetching depreciation and amortization data: {e}")
        return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ticker = 'MSFT'
    cik = get_cik_from_ticker(ticker)
    dep_amort_value = fetch_data_from_sec_edgar(cik, ticker)
    print(dep_amort_value)
```

Comment: It looks to me like the keys are actually different, `us-gaap` uses `DepreciationDepletionAndAmortization` but `msft` uses `DepreciationAmortizationAndOther` so you'd need to swap both.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Yes, they have different sub identifiers, but even substituting in the correct key doesn't work.

Comment: Got it, well it'll probably be difficult to answer without seeing a lot more of the code behind it, but in a case like this i'd probably start debugging by checking out what keys are available on `companyFacts.json()['facts']['msft'].keys()`, if there isn't anything that looks like it there may be a problem with whatever is parsing and creating the `companyFacts` or like you suggested, it might not be present in `facts` at all

Comment: Thanks for adding more of that code, I took a look at: https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyfacts/CIK0000789019.json which is the json I think your script is pulling. But browsing through the JSON in a browser we don't really see some of the keys you're looking for, so I think your best bet might be to browse the JSON directly to see if you can find what you need

Comment: It's not there, which is why its confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with custom tags using beautiful soup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000095017023054855/msft-20230930.htm"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'YOUR EMAIL'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

dep_amort_tag = soup.find('ix:nonfraction', {'name': 'msft:DepreciationAmortizationAndOther'})

if dep_amort_tag:

    depreciation_amortization_value = dep_amort_tag.text
    print(f"Depreciation, Amortization, and Other: {depreciation_amortization_value}")
else:
    print("Depreciation and Amortization data not found.")
```